# Redirect (big) output to a txt file

Tags: python, redirect

I've written a simple python code  which extracts rows from a big table and put them into arrays. After printing the result that I get on the terminal is just an array with the first two and last two elements

```
[0.75 0.90  ..., 0.78 0.79]
```

I've tried to redirect the output to a .txt file using

```
saveout = sys.stdout
outline = open("file.txt", "w")
sys.stdout = outline
```

but I get the same problem in the txt file. 
How can I redirect the complete array to the file?

Comment: Are you using `numpy` or `scipy` perhaps?

Comment: What does the code look like that does the printing?

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html for `numpy` printing options. Don't use `print` to 'save' your array to a file though.

Comment: Hi Martijn I've fixed the problem! Tanx a lot!!

Comment: @user2044983, you should answer your question so that other people know what you did.

Comment: Of course. As Martijin suggested I've added the following line to my code 

    np.set_printoptions(precision=3, threshold=10, edgeitems=1000)

and now in the file.txt all values are displayed.